# Saving a BluetoothDevice object after the application closes

Tags: android, bluetooth, global-variables

I would like to save the last bluetooth device my application has connected to. I want to not prompt the user at all, if there is a previous bluetooth connection. They will have the option of connecting to a new device, but they do not need to. If they opt to not choose a connection, they will use the application regularly, and then when the bluetooth device is needed, it will connect to the most recent device.

I have tried using the code provided in `Tudor Luca's` answer below, but the object will not write to the file. I am getting a `NotSerializableException`. The object which I am trying to save is a `BluetoothDevice` which is imported with `import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice`.

This is what I have tried to do to make the bluetooth device serializable:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;

public class SerializableObjects implements Serializable {
    private BluetoothDevice device;

    public SerializableObjects( BluetoothDevice device ) {
        this.device = device;
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getDevice() {
        return this.device;
    }
}
```

The LogCat Returns this:

```
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641): java.io.NotSerializableException: android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1143)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1241)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at my.eti.commander.LocalObjects.writeObjectToFile(LocalObjects.java:29)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at my.eti.commander.MainMenu$1.handleMessage(MainMenu.java:460)
12-11 17:46:24.032: W/System.err(24641):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 17:46:24.036: W/System.err(24641):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-11 17:46:24.036: W/System.err(24641):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-11 17:46:24.036: W/System.err(24641):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 17:46:24.036: W/System.err(24641):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-11 17:46:24.036: W/System.err(24641):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-11 17:46:24.036: W/System.err(24641):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-11 17:46:24.036: W/System.err(24641):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: A matter of terminology. A field in an Activity cannot be global since an Activity has a lesser scope than the application.  There seems to be an annoying habit amongst Android devs of calling class level variables "global".  As developers, we should strive to be accurate

Comment: Sorry, changed it. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to directly serialize the BluetoothDevice class. Even if you serialize it, I do not think you will be able to re-use the object after the application closed. Instead, I have a helper class that will store the address of the device. You can save the device address and name and read that information later. You can then perform a discovery/search for bonded devices and obtain corresponding device.

Here is a helper class I typically use

```
public class BluetoothState implements Serializable {
    public static final int STATE_NOT_CONNECTED = 1;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 1;

    public static final String filename = "btState.pref";

    public static int connectionState = STATE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    public static String deviceAddress = "00:00:00:00:00:00";
    public static String deviceName = "";

    public static void setConnectionState(boolean connected,BluetoothDevice device) {
        if(connected)
            connectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
        else
            connectionState = STATE_NOT_CONNECTED;

        if(device != null) {
            deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
            deviceName = device.getName();
        }

    }

    public static void saveConnectionState(Context cxt) throws IOException {        
        FileOutputStream fos = cxt.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);       
        oos.writeInt(connectionState);
        oos.writeUTF(deviceAddress);
        oos.writeUTF(deviceName);
    }

    public static void loadConnectionState(Context cxt) throws IOException {        
        FileInputStream fis = cxt.openFileInput(filename);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);     
        connectionState = ois.readInt();
        deviceAddress = ois.readUTF();
        deviceName = ois.readUTF();
    }

    public static BluetoothDevice getDevice() {
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(!btAdapter.isEnabled())
            btAdapter.enable();

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        for(BluetoothDevice d : pairedDevices)
            if(d.getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(deviceAddress))
                return d;

        return null;        
    }

}
```

Comment: This is actually not entirely accurate. The BluetoothDevice can actually be serialized and reused to connect. The only problem is that only the address will be serialized. To work around this, I simply wrapped the BluetoothDevice inside of another class where I would store the name and anything else I needed for display purposes. I was then able to deserialize the wrapper and use the contained BluetoothDevice to make quick reconnections in my app.

Comment: When this solution was posted 2 years ago, BluetoothDevice object was not Serializable and required this workaround. I am not sure what the latest library does.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your object to a private file, an load it from there.
The only thing you have to do to your object, is to make it `implements Serializable`.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

/**
 *
 * Writes/reads an object to/from a private local file
 * 
 *
 */
public class LocalObjects{


    /**
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param object
     * @param filename
     */
    public static void witeObjectToFile(Context context, Object object, String filename) {

        ObjectOutputStream objectOut = null;
        try {

            FileOutputStream fileOut = context.openFileOutput(filename, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            objectOut.writeObject(object);
            fileOut.getFD().sync();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (objectOut != null) {
                try {
                    objectOut.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // do nowt
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param filename
     * @return
     */
    public static Object readObjectFromFile(Context context, String filename) {

        ObjectInputStream objectIn = null;
        Object object = null;
        try {

            FileInputStream fileIn = context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput(filename);
            objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            object = objectIn.readObject();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // Do nothing
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (objectIn != null) {
                try {
                    objectIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // do nowt
                }
            }
        }

        return object;
    }

}
```

So basicaly what you want to do, is to get the last paired device, right?
Here how the code should look like:

1. You need a `BluetoothAdapter` for all Bluetooth activity:

   `BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {

            //Then your device does not support Bluetooth

        }`
2. Make sure Bluetooth is enabled

   `if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
   Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
   startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
   }`
3. Get previous paired devices

   `Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
   // If there are paired devices
   if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
       // Loop through paired devices
       for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
           // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
           mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
       }
   }`

For a full tutorial how to use the Bluetooth connectivity, check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)

Comment: This answer will work for custom objects, but I am using the BluetoothDevice which is part of a library, and is not serializable. This unfortunately does not answer the question

Comment: @JuiCe Basicaly what you want to do is to get the last BluetoothDevice that you have paired with, right?

Comment: I may be incorrect, but I think it is the last device I was connected to, not the last device I paired with. I have multiple devices paired, but can only connect to one. I want the last device paired. I have all of the above code in my project already. I want to save the last device I was connected to so the next time the app is launched, the user does not need to choose the device, but when a bluetooth connection is needed, the last used device will be used.

Comment: I do not know why I cannot edit the above comment, but the third sentence should be `I want the last device connected`, NOT `I want the last device paired`.